# mySQL for loop stops working after 31 row updates [Actually PHP related]

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I have a form that uses a PHP for loop after it is submitted. The loop updates individual rows in the database one after the next based on the form data submitted. However, I've noticed that the loop stops working if there are more than 31 rows that need to be updated.  It will update everything perfectly for the first 31 loops but then will not work after the 31st loop?

**UPDATE:** I've done some testing and it seems that the loop never finishes. It just refreshes the page in the browser instead of printing the results. What is causing this?

Is there a MYSQL query setting somewhere that is causing this?

Here is my loop's code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$total_results2;$i++) 
{
$strSQL = 'UPDATE timesheets_items SET ';
$strSQL .= 'time_1 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_1']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_2 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_2']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_3 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_3']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_4 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_4']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_5 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_5']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_6 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_6']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_7 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_7']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_8 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_8']) .  '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_9 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_9']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_10 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_10']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_11 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_11']) .  '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_12 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_12']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_13 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_13']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_14 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_14']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', time_total = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_time_total']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_1 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_1']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_2 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_2']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_3 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_3']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_4 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_4']) .'"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_5 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_5']) .  '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_6 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_6']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_7 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_7']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_8 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_8']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_9 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_9']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_10 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_10']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_11 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_11']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_12 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_12']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_13 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_13']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_14 = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_14']) . '"';
$strSQL .= ', ot_total = "' . convert_time($_POST['item_' . $i . '_ot_total']) . '"';

$strSQL .= 'WHERE week_start = "' . $week_start . '" AND employee_id = "' . $id . '" AND project_number = "' . $_POST['item_' . $i . '_project_number'] .'" AND task = "' . $_POST['item_' . $i . '_task'] .'"';
mysql_query($strSQL); 
}
```

Comment: As a side note: you may want to consider using nested loops.

Comment: Table design change! Prepared Statements! Please.

Comment: Wow, you might want to use arrays for your form field names...

Comment: Is it possible you are hitting the `max_execution_time` limit of your PHP install?

Comment: The execution time is extremely fast on a quick server so I don't believe it is hitting the max time.

Comment: how did you reach this conclusion of 31 loops?

Comment: I reached the conclusion after adding records one-by-one to my form and submitting.  It repeatedly update rows correctly until I add a 32nd record to the form.  I wonder if it's a buffer / memory setting with MySQL ?

Comment: I just updated the post after noticing that the loop is never finishing and doesn't move onto the next step. The page refreshes instead of printing the output. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe `$_POST['item_' . $i . '_project_number']` is `'; DROP DATABASE foo; --`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the issue !  The problem was caused by my version of PHP (5.3) and the amount of input variables allowed by PHP on a form.

The problem ended up not being MySQL related at all. The bug found was limiting how many form variables were taken in by PHP thus not allowing MySQL to ever get to see those variables when it came time to run the repeated queries loop.

To resolve the issue, I had to update to PHP (5.4 or greater) and then set the "max_input_vars" setting to 3000. (The default setting only allows 1000.)

I hope this helps anyone who ever comes across this same problem.